# Arranging 1's and 0's in an array together

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers say:

```
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Now using the minimum number of moves I want to group the 1's and 0's with condition that a number can be swapped with its adjacent position only either left or right.

```
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 -->     1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 -->     
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 --> 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 --> 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 --> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 --> 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Here it took 6 moves so the program should return 6.

Here is my program:

```
public static int arrange(List<Integer> nums) {
    int n = nums.size();
    boolean modified = false;
    int first = nums.get(0);
    int index = -1;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (first != nums.get(i)) {
            index = index == -1 ? i : index;
            modified = true;
        }
        if (modified) {
            if(first == nums.get(i)) {
                count += i - index;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return count - 1;
    }
}
```

This program looks good for some inputs. But I am missing a condition here, I am going from position 0 to size of input and not considering all possible conditions like going in reverse or changing the order in mid-ways etc.

Can you please help me with what is the correct approach here.

Comment: Aren't there only 2 possible solutions? All the ones at the start or the end? It seems like you can just try your solution or your solution in reverse. In that case you are iterating the list twice. Or do you need a solution where only 1s are contiguous is valid, i.e. 000111110000?

Comment: I think for this input `1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1` the minimum number of moves is 1. Because the last `1` can be moved to the first index, so the resulting output is `1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`. Do let me know your thoughts on the answer I've provided.

Comment: @NicholasK, we cannot treat the array as circular

Comment: Ah looks like I missed that *tiny* detail and wasted my time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that there are two possibilities for the final position. The leftmost element is a 1 or a 0.

Suppose you are aiming for a leftmost 1. The first 1 you see going from left to right is obviously the one you want at the first position (all other ones will just take even more swaps to reach the first position). In fact, each 1 you see would belong the next position after the 1s you have already seen.

The same is true for 0s if you are aiming for a leftmost 0.

How many steps are needed for this? Simple. Let's say you see a 1 at position `i` and that you have already seen `x` 1s to the left already. Then the index of this 1 in the final position will be `x` according to the analysis above. Number of steps = `i - x`.

Here's a simple implementation:

```
public static int arrange(List<Integer> nums) {
    int n = nums.size();
    int seen1s = 0;
    int seen0s = 0;
    int steps_left1 = 0;
    int steps_left0 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (nums.get(i) == 1) {
            steps_left1 += i - seen1s;
            seen1s += 1;
        } else {
            steps_left0 += i - seen0s;
            seen0s += 1;
        }
    }
    return Math.min(steps_left1, steps_left0);
}
```